# Script blocking sometimes when the process from the utility w3m is running

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a script that calculates the word distribution over the web (basically the occurrences of the words)

what I do is generating random pages of a search engine, extracting links and calculating words from them sites.

I was using google, but the CAPTCHA blocked my requests
now I'm using bing 
Everything works just fine, but there is a weird problem

at a certain point, after I scanned like 100 to 300 pages, my program totally blocks doing nothing

I check ps x and there is a process of the utility w3m that is trying to download something, but it's like idling

if I kill the process, then my script continues running without problems and like nothing happened...

What could it be? some error code I wrote, bing blocking too many requests?

I was thinking a very unelegant solution

basically I can kill the process if it's idling for like more than 5 seconds or so, what do you think and how can this be done? 
I'm afraid my whole program blocks at that point so I need an external script that checks the processes running and kills the w3m ones if they block

thanks a lot and sorry for your time.
Really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some pages are gone or remote server doesn't response and w3m hangs on it waiting the timeout exceeds.
By the way that's pretty unsual to use `w3m` in script. Usually `curl` or `wget` are used for that purpose.

For example, `wget` has `--timeout=` option to avoid such problems.

After fast googling I found nothing useful about timeouts in `w3m`. Hope you'll be a bit luckier than me.

Comment: I used timeout 20s w3m. It works perfectly now, timeout basically kills the command after x seconds. Thanks by the way for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

> after I scanned like 100 to 300 pages

You may be exceeding certain thresholds set by the search providers to prevent repetitive scraping.  If the search provider guesses you're a loose bot, they may throttle your results for a short while.